# TreeMap overwrite values

Tags: java

i'm having a problem with my treemap

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int value;


            map.put(value, uuid);
            values.add(value);
```

i try to sort the value to get something like this

```
Player:
  PlayerName1: 83
  PlayerName2: 5
```

i use this to get the score :

```
System.out.println(map.get(values.get(0)) + " : " + values.get(0));
```

but if one of the player have the same number of points the map return this :

```
  PlayerName1 : 83
  PlayerName1 : 83
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: 'Try to sort the value' how?

Comment: Collections.sort(values, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: So post that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you using a `Player` class? You could have a `List<Player>` which would allow for duplicates, and can still be sorted by points.

```
class Player {
    private final String name;
    private int points;

    ....

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }  

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s: %d", name, points);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
//... add players
players.sort(Comparator.comparing(Player::getPoints).reversed());

System.out.println("Players:");
players.stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println("\t" + p));
```